# Printing the longest substring in a list of letters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The task asks to print the longest substring in the alphabetical order. For example:

**'kotafgovlav'** -> longest alphabetical substring: **'afgov'**

or if they are both equal long then the first one should be taken:

**'abcbcd'** -> longest alphabetical substring: **'abc'**

Here is the what I've done so far:

```
DECLARE 
x varchar2(12) := 'kotafgovlav';
ind varchar2(12);
BEGIN 
  for i in 1..length(x) loop
  if substr(x, i, 1) > substr(x, i-1, 1)
    end if; 
  end loop; 
END;
```

As you can see, I didn't get the result that i wanted (not even close). Can you maybe give me a hint/suggestions to solve this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the issue is that you leapt straight into writing some code instead of designing your program first. There are various procedural solutions with simple syntax, but you need to work out the loops and switches. Doesn't your course cover program design? Not even flowcharts?

Comment: It is true what you said. Unfortunately, we haven't learned it yet (it's been 2,5 weeks), the program design course starts next month. But since I realize how important it is, I think I'd read more about this first. Thanks @APC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this block.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  x         VARCHAR2(12) := 'kotafgovlav';
  l_substr  VARCHAR2(12) := SUBSTR(x,1,1);
  l_longest VARCHAR2(12) := SUBSTR(x,1,1);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 2..length(x)
  LOOP
    IF ASCII( SUBSTR(x,i,1) ) >= ASCII( SUBSTR(x,i-1,1) ) THEN
      l_substr                := l_substr||SUBSTR(x,i,1);
    ELSE
      IF LENGTH(l_substr) >= LENGTH(l_longest) THEN
        l_longest         := l_substr;
      END IF;
      l_substr := SUBSTR(x,i,1);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('longest substring '||l_longest);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sorry for bothering you again. In the 10th line, l_substr||Substr(x, i, 1), is the '||' operator here for concatenation?

Comment: @Chopsticks [yes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)

Comment: @chopsticks Yes. You can also use the `CONCAT` function if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single SQL statement:

```
SELECT substring
FROM   (
  SELECT RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY LEVEL DESC ) As rnk,
         SUBSTR(
           str,
           CONNECT_BY_ROOT( idx ),
           idx - CONNECT_BY_ROOT( idx ) + 1
         ) AS substring
  FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL AS idx,
           str,
           SUBSTR( str, LEVEL, 1 ) As value
    FROM   ( SELECT 'kotafgovlav' AS str FROM DUAL )
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( str )
  )
  WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR value   < value
         AND PRIOR idx + 1 = idx
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue with your code, getting out of your loop with `exit` could be a solution;

```
DECLARE 
x varchar2(12) := 'kotafgovlav';
ind varchar2(12);
BEGIN 
  for i in 1..length(x) loop
    if substr(x, i, 1) > substr(x, i-1, 1) then
      dbms_output.put_line('i:'||i);  
      -- here do something because your test is ok
      exit;  -- exits current loop
    end if; 
  end loop; 
END;
```

... Then it's all algorithm. First you must learn PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make you understand used dbms_output to verify. Below is the code :

```
   DECLARE 
    x varchar2(12) := 'pqrsabc1de';
    ind varchar2(12);
    counter number := 1;
    max_counter number := 0;
    str_cr varchar2(100);
    str varchar2(100);
    BEGIN 
    str_cr := str_cr || substr(x, 1, 1);
      for i in 1..length(x) loop
     -- dbms_output.put_line('one:'||substr(x, i, 1));
     -- dbms_output.put_line('two:'||substr(x, i+1, 1));
          if substr(x, i+1, 1) > substr(x, i, 1) then
             counter := counter + 1;
             str_cr := str_cr || substr(x, i+1, 1);
          -- dbms_output.put_line('str_cr:'||str_cr);
         --     dbms_output.put_line('counter:'||counter);
         else
          if max_counter < counter then
              max_counter := counter;
               str := str_cr;
               str_cr := substr(x, i+1, 1);
               counter := 1;
          else 
            str_cr := substr(x, i+1, 1);
            counter := 1;
          end if;
          -- dbms_output.put_line('str:'||str);
           -- exit;  -- exits current loop
        end if; 

      end loop; 
       dbms_output.put_line('str_final:'||str);
    END;
```